# How to have 2 different locale directories in django project?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-rest-framework

I need to have two different locale directories in my django project.
Because there are some translations in third-party apps like rest_auth which are not available for my language.
We translated them manually in .po file, but the problem is whenever I run:

```
python manage.py makemessages
```

It scans the project and get rid of all the manually translated strings!
So I want a directory for third party app translations (which django ignores it and doesn't update it), and another locale directory for my own stuff which get updated everytime I run makemessages.

p.s: I already added the second locale folder to LOCALE_PATHS in settings.

Comment: You're saving the manually translated strings in the additional folder in `LOCALE_PATHS` and they are being deleted? I haven't played with translations in a long time, but that doesn't seem right if `LOCALE_PATHS` is supposed to let you override base translations in your project, as [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) alludes.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida No they are not being deleted.
I want to have control over these folders and specify which one get updated and which one get ignored.

Comment: You said `makemessages` is scanning the project and getting rid of the manually translated strings. That's what I meant with "being deleted". What is disappearing?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida When I use makemessages, Manually translated strings in first locale folder get deleted, but not in the second one.
Is there a way so I can control which locale directory get updated and which one not?
I used --ignore option but seems it's not working for me

Comment: Is "first locale folder" the first folder in `LOCALE_PATHS`? Only that folder is updated when you run `makemessages` in the project root. I don't know what the behavior is supposed to be regarding deleting manually created strings there, but if you put your manual translations in any folder other than the first, they shouldn't be touched.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida So I guess that's the normal behaviour. Only first folder in LOCALE_PATHS gets updated and the rest are ignored,right?
I think I got my answer. But out of curiosity, Is there a way to update the rest of folders as well?

Comment: According to the documentation, towards the end of [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files), yes, only the first file is updated, if the strings belong to an app with no `locale` folder. The other folders in `LOCALE_PATHS` don't get updated, but you can do the update  per app by creating a `locale` folder in the app, and then the folders in `LOCALE_PATHS` will only have the manual overrides.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and managed to solve it by creating two separate directories. The first directory specified in your `LOCALE_PATHS` will be used by Django and overwritten based on your project when you run the `makemessages` command. The second path will still be compiled when you run `compilemessages` but the `.po` file won't be overwritten and you can have your third party translations here.

You can implement it along the following way. Start by defining two `LOCALE_PATHS` in your `settings.py`. Specify the one that should *not* be overwritten as the last one:

```py
# settings.py

LOCALE_PATHS = [BASE_DIR / 'locale', BASE_DIR / 'locale-3rd-party']
```

Create the corresponding i18n folders. Make sure you have a folder structure like below (replace with whatever language(s) you are using instead of `da_DK`):

```
your_project/
    locale/da_DK/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    locale-3rd-party/da_DK/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

Running `makemessages` will now update the file(s) at `locale/*/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`, removing all strings that no longer occur in the project, but `locale-3rd-party/*/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` will be left untouched.